# Keras Convolution layer : model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3 input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)))

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Good day. Decided to jump into convolutional neural network and encountered with this error.

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from parser import load_data 

training_data = load_data(Downloads/train)
test_data = load_data(Downloads/test1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3 input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)))

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

Error:

`File "test1.py", line 9`
    `model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3 input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)))`

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot a comma in that line after the second three, so it should be:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)))
```